# las variables no me funcionan con lo sockets

Tags: python-3.x

estoy estudiando python per me he quedado atascado,el caso es que si pongo los valores directamente en el codigo el programa funciona correctamente, pero en cuento cambio los valores de  "misock.connect" y "misock.send(cmd)" por variables me da error de conexion.

haber si alguien que domine el tema me puede echar una mano

```
import socket

direccion= list()
lugar = input("intruduzca una URL: ")
try:
    if lugar.startswith("http:"):
        direccion = lugar.split("/")
        conexion = direccion[2]
    else:
        exit()
except:
    print("el formato de la direccion debe comenzar por HTTP://")
    exit()
misock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
misock.connect((conexion, 80))
cmd = "GET "lugar" HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode()
misock.send(cmd)

while True:
    datos = misock.recv(512)
    if len(datos) < 1:
        break
    print(datos.decode(),end="")

misock.close()
```

el código de arriba no funciona pero si en cambio escribo este:

```
import socket

direccion= list()
lugar = input("intruduzca una URL: ")
try:
    if lugar.startswith("http:"):
        direccion = lugar.split("/")
        conexion = direccion[2]
    else:
        exit()
except:
    print("el formato de la direccion debe comenzar por HTTP://")
    exit()
misock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
misock.connect(("data.pr4e.org", 80))
cmd = "GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode()
misock.send(cmd)

while True:
    datos = misock.recv(512)
    if len(datos) < 1:
        break
    print(datos.decode(),end="")

misock.close()
```

si funciona, alguien me puede explicar??

Comment: A qué te refieres con que no funciona? Llega a ejecutarse y no sucede lo que esperabas o te da un error?

Comment: Error de sintaxis, no puedes hacer  `"GET "lugar" HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"`. Podrías usar f strings, así `f"GET {lugar} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"`

Comment: También trata de imprimir la variable `conexion` para saber su contenido

Comment: ya he probado a imprimir la variable conexion y el resultado en teoría es correcto si la imprimes da: "data.pr4e.org", es caso es que ya solo cambiando el valor por la variable ya da error

Comment: Yo creo que el error en cambio está en la asignación de la variable `cmd`, como dice @Christian en su comentario anterior